# My Producer tag in PostScript to PDF metadata properties is not showing

Tags: pdf, postscript, xmp

All metadata appearing exactly what i mentioned in POSTSCRIPT except **"Producer"** tag while Converting that POSTSCRIPT file into PDF Using Adobe Distiller

```
/CreationDate (D:20150812091839)
/ModDate  (D:20150812091839)
/Title (Arslan Ahmed)
/Creator (James Bond)
/Producer (Harry Potter)
/Author (Sunny)
/Subject (Working)
/Keywords (Prius arslan)
/DOCINFO pdfmark
```

I want producer name "Harry Potter" which i mentioned in POSTSCRIPT not Distiller name.

**OR**

Is there a way to use any converter who show my producer name rather than showing there producer name?

Comment: Is your software the Producer or is Abode's Distiller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Adobe pdfmark reference :

> Producer string Optional. The name of the application that converted
>   the document from its native form to PDF. Note: Distiller ignores the
>   setting of this attribute

So no, you can't alter the Producer using Adobe Acrobat Distiller and the DOCINFO pdfmark. Given that your input is PostScript (at least I assume it is, since you are discussing Distiller) you could use Ghostscript instead.